# increasing fraction digits in the result Anylogic

Tags: des, anylogic

Can anyone knows how can we increase the decimal places of the results that Anylogic is giving us? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you please specify what exactly you are talking about? What numbers are you getting and what would you like to see?

Comment: Sure. Thanks for your comment. In my model I have some variables that show different performance metrics such as queue length or waiting time in queue. After each run, depending on the input values that I specify, these variables will show different results. However, in all these outputs, results are shown with at most 3 decimal digits (precision). I need to increase these decimal places to 6 digits. How can I do that?

Comment: where do you see the 3-digit outputs? Java Double values have more precision than that. So it is trimmed for your convenience. Where do you observe 3 digits?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pyqV.png

Comment: these are just visual outputs, the underlying objects still hold the values to much higher precision.

Answer (score 0):

Access the actual object to get the high-precision value.

If you want to see the full numbers at runtime, you can use a "Text" object from the Presentation library and change its dynamic text (see the help) to `AQLPatient1a.getMean()` or `probExc1A`

Move the text object near those objects to see the difference at runtime.

You could even hide the variables and statistics objects and only display relevant text objects. Set "visible" to false in the object properties.

Comment: I got the results for my variables but it does not work for the statistic modules I am getting an error which is "Description: The method roundToDecimal(double, int) in the type Utilities is not applicable for the arguments (StatisticsDiscrete, int). Location: Modeltest1/Main/text9 - Text". Can you please help me to resolve this issue? Thank you in advance.